# Hosting domain on AWS with hostgator email mx/a record changes

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, email-server, mx-record

I am hosting my email with a remote provider (HostGator), and need to alter my `MX` and `A` records so as to point incoming email to this host.  What I have done so far is as follows in my Route53 management, but I am unsure if it's correct:

1. Created a new `MX` record for `mail.example.com`(I set the TTL on both the HostGator side and AWS to 3600 as I don't want to wait longer for propagation)
2. Created a new `A` record that points to the IP address of the mail server.  What I am confused about is do I make the  name `mail.example.com`, or just `example.com`

What else do I need to do, as I am still not getting any incoming messages on the mail server.

Comment: If your MX records designates mail.sitename.com then you need an A record for mail.sitename.com.

Comment: Ok, I believe I have done this, is there any other changes that I need to make? when I check the leafdns it appears to not have propogated as of yet.

Comment: Give the real name and people could help you with relevant information.

Comment: You can only set a TTL in one place, so unclear what you've done. Mail servers don't typically need an A record unless you want to run a web mail system for the domain, MX is fine.